# ngshow flickers content with nganimate

Tags: angularjs, flicker, ng-animate, ng-show

I am noticing when switching between Previous and Next, there is a flicker of the upcoming content before the previous is removed.

Is the ngAnimate library causing a delay? Is there a better approach to what I'm aiming to do?

http://embed.plnkr.co/V6RPX8Q5N9pwrgsqIfGb/preview

Comment: nothing is wrong with ngAnimate (I see your plunker). Your problem is the selected effect... if you want to hide something like an accordeon, you need to use an effect with changes the height of your div. You has used a fade effect. Look at this: http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/appear

Comment: If you want a cross-fade effect you have to use something like `position: absolute` (at least while animating) on the elements so they can appear in the same spot: http://plnkr.co/edit/qQ7qIQZKdTe2BDAx4luX?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @JoaozitoPolo and @ExplosionPills! I'll try those out. Looks like the `position: absolute` is more along the lines of what I'm looking for.